# How to make two buttons the same size?

Tags: html, css

How can I fix this because if the text is long the button will be longer.

[image]

```css
button {
 border: none;
 padding: 1.1em 6.5em;
 background: #00abc6;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 border-radius: 0px;
}

button:hover {
 background: #3E3E3E;
}
```

```html
<button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">Login</button>
    <center><p>Or</p></center>
         <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-2">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to set a width and height for your button and to centre text horizontally and vertically use the following:

```
 width:120px;
 height:50px;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:1.1em;
 font-size:1.1em;
```

width and height can be set to match your desired measurements.

This can be used for future demonstration:

https://jsfiddle.net/j9njkwkq/

**EDIT:**
of course you can add cursor:pointer in order to get the "right" button effect on a browser.

Answer (score 3):

In this case you should use. min-width attribute.
Use `min-width:100px`

Comment: Why `min-width` and not `width`?

Answer (score 2):

Add width to the style definition, for example:

```
max-width: 100px;
```

or just:

```
width: 100px;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ghc9aw3w/

Of course you have to adjust the value to the text's required length.

Comment: probably want `min-width` rather than max otherwise you could could end up with the text being clipped

Comment: I assumed OP doesn't want the button to extend, which would occur with `min-width` set. I also assume that this is needed for particular text, which has constant and known length.

Comment: Ah I assumed the opposite that he wanted the buttons the same length but set to the longest button so it wouldn't look clipped as in your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ghc9aw3w/1/

Answer (score 1):

```css
button {
 border: none;
 padding: 1.1em 6.5em;
 background: #00abc6;
 color: #fff;
 font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size: 1.1em;
 border-radius: 0px;
width:200px
}

button:hover {
 background: #3E3E3E;
}
```

```html
<button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">Login</button>
    <center><p>Or</p></center>
         <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-2">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a wrapper and than set the width to 100%

```css
#login {
    width: 300px;
}


button {
    border: none;
    padding: 1.1em 6.5em;
    background: #00abc6;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size: 1.1em;
    border-radius: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

button:hover {
    background: #3E3E3E;
}
```

```html
<div id='login'>
    <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">Login</button>
    <center><p>Or</p></center>
    <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-2">Register</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give "width" for the class .md-trigger or button to make that same even if long text is entered.

Answer (score 0):

For perfect styling wrap the contents  inside a div

https://jsfiddle.net/ghc9aw3w/2/

```
<div class="btnwrap">
<button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-1">Login</button>
      <center><p>Or</p></center>
     <button class="md-trigger" data-modal="modal-2">Register</button>
</div>
```

then the style would be

```
.btnwrap{
width:200px;
overflow:hidden;
}

button {
width:100%;
display:block;
border: none;
padding: 1.1em 5em;
background: #00abc6;
color: #fff;
font-family: 'TitilliumText22LRegular', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 1.1em;
border-radius: 0px;
text-align:center;

}

button:hover {
background: #3E3E3E;
}
```